# Incrementing a single parameter in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get the hour component of an object, which is an int, and increment it by 1. So 5 would be 6. I tried to do clocks[i].getHour() = clocks[i].getHour()+1, but this was not allowed and would say I need a variable on the left.

```
public void daylightSavingsTime(Clock[] clocks) {
    for(int i = 0; i <clocks.length; i++) {
        int a = clocks[i].getHour()+1;

    }
```

Comment: instead of trying to do `clocks[i].getHour() = clocks[i].getHour()+1` which will cause a compilation error. create a setter for the `hour` field and then do `clocks[i].setHour(clocks[i].getHour()+1)`

Comment: Please be careful about hour incrementation for date object: 23 + 1 should become 0 for hour, and the day should be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'd need to write/use a setter function *setHour(int newHour)* ,
and then you could do something along the lines of:

```
public void daylightSavingsTime(Clock[] clocks) {
    for(int i = 0; i <clocks.length; i++) {
        clocks[i].setHour(clocks[i].getHour()+1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of your statement.

```
clocks[i].getHour() = clocks[i].getHour()+1;
//To simplify
Clock clock = clocks[i];
clock.getHour() = clock.getHour()+1; //thing you are trying to do.
```

Suppose clock hours field is 6. What the compiler will do. When it sees `clock.getHours()` it knows the value is 6. To compiler your statement looks like

```
6 = 6+1
```

Obviously no language wants to change the value of `6` to `7`

But `int a = clocks[i].getHour()+1;` is a valid statement as `a` will be assigned to `7`.

To increment the hour in clock just use just do

```
clock.hours = clocks[i].getHour()+1;
```

but now hours property is public and can be easily abused like `clock.hours = 100;` but we may not want it to be 100, but to increase the date as 100 > 24. So use set method  like `clock.setHour(a+1)` this method will internally handle the hour like

```
Class Clock{
// like that.. it may be different..
    void setHour(int hour){
        this.day += hour/24;
        this.hour += hour%24; 
    }  
}
```